# How to extract column values based on applying condition on other column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook, data-science, data-analysis

```
print("Someone has killed {:.4f} with headshot, have {} kills, while the most kills ever recorded is {}.".format(pubg_main_df['headshotKills'].max(), pubg_main_df[pubg_main_df['headshotKills']==pubg_main_df['headshotKills'].max()]['kills'], pubg_main_df['kills'].max()))
```

What I want is to get the value of 'Kills' where the headshotKills is max.

But I am getting:

Someone has killed 26.0000 with headshot, have 910050    60
Name: kills, dtype: int64 kills, while the most kills ever recorded is 60.

It should have been:

Someone has killed 26.0000 with headshot, have 42 kills, while the most kills ever recorded is 60.

Type of the variables are:

headshotKills      int64

kills              int64

Please help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html):

```
#sample data
pubg_main_df= pd.DataFrame({'kills':[60,  42], 'headshotKills':[3, 26]})

print("Someone has killed {:.4f} with headshot, have {} kills, while the most kills ever recorded is {}."
            .format(pubg_main_df['headshotKills'].max(), 
                    pubg_main_df.set_index('kills')['headshotKills'].idxmax(), 
                    pubg_main_df['kills'].max()))


Someone has killed 26.0000 with headshot, have 42 kills, while the most kills ever recorded is 60.
```

Comment: What I want is to find out the value of the 'Kills' for the same row where the headshot kills are maximum

Comment: @PrakashShelke - so `pubg_main_df.set_index('kills')['headshotKills'].idxmax()` not working?

Comment: nope,
'Someone has killed 26.0000 with headshot, have 60 kills, while the most kills ever recorded is 60'

Above is the result.

Comment: @PrakashShelke - If check `print(pubg_main_df.sort_values('headshotKills', ascending=False))`  what is first row? After sorting first row show row with maximum `headshotKills` and kills also. If there is kills=60 then your output is correct.

Comment: Yes! Thanks @jezrael
headshotKills
26
kills
60

Yes! Thanks alot :)